# filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON

Tags: collections, pymongo

> TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or "
> TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

```
prev = {"name", "Amy"}
next_ = {"$set": {"address", "Ahmadabad"}}
collection.update_one(prev, next_)
```

Answer (score 1):

A subtle one, but an easy mistake to make; replace the comma (`,`) with a colon(`:`)

```
prev = {"name": "Amy"}
next_ = {"$set": {"address": "Ahmadabad"}}
collection.update_one(prev, next_)
```

pymongo typically requires dictionary parameters. If you use a comma, that is the syntax for creating a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets); perfectly valid in python, but no use in pymongo.